# How to customize the JSQMessagesViewController inputs?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to display `UIDatePicker` on click of `JSQMessagesViewController`'s input text field. Also want to do Customization of incoming bubble layout, Please refer the image below.

[image]

Comment: why you need to UIDatePicker  in chatting or you just want to show the time at what time the message would send.

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal The app is proposed for service industry so,I have to ask the date of invoice as input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

For custom chat bubbles you have to implement the method

```
- (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

of `JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource`.

The returned `JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource` instance it basically an abstraction for two stretch images. One if the normal bubble, the other one is the highlighted bubble. Of course in your case you need actually 4 images (incoming bubble normal, incoming bubble highlighted, outgoing bubble normal, outgoing bubble highlighted).

If hope that will get you started.